# Defining a dynamic variable

Tags: macros

### Goal :

I would like to create a variable that could be dynamically updated.

### Context :

Every chapter of my document has a specific keyword (actually a bibtex entry). And sometimes, I need to print it, or use it as a parameter for another command. So I need to define a first command that stores the keyword, and another command that prints it. Thereby, for every new chapter, the keyword changes, and so does the variable.

### So far :

This is the commands I (think I) would need :

```
\newcommand{\aNewChapter}[2]{%
  \textbf{#1} % The title of the chapter
  \setVariable{#2} % The definition of the variable
}
\newcommand{\setVariable}[1]{#1} 
\newcommand{\printVariable}{???}
\begin{document}
\aNewChapter{The first chapter}{keyword1}
Some text...
\printVariable % this should, in this case, print 'keyword1'
The rest of the text
\end{document}
```

The idea doesn't seem massively complex, but I can't find any solution to achieve it. It would be easy if I set the variable manually, rather than with a parameter. But I need this 'dynamic' way of doing. The problem is then that I don't know how to print it.

It seems so easy that I almost feel dumb to ask that...

Comment: I think `\newcommand` is already what you're looking for :-) If you define a "Variable" with `\newcommand{\myvariable}`, set and update it with `\renewcommand{\myvariable}`, you can print it by just saying `\myvariable`.

Comment: I don't think it works, I need to set the variable with an argument. I updated my post with more content to show how it should work...

Comment: Have you tried replacing `\setVariable{#2}` with `\renewcommand{\myVariable}{#2}` and `\printVariable` with `\myVariable`?

Comment: Yes. It only prints the title of the chapter. Not the keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a complete example based on my comments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\aNewChapter}[2]{%
  \textbf{#1} % The title of the chapter
  \setVariable{#2} % The definition of the variable
}
\newcommand\myVariable{}
\newcommand{\setVariable}[1]{\renewcommand{\myVariable}{#1}} 
\newcommand{\printVariable}{\myVariable}
\begin{document}
\aNewChapter{The first chapter}{keyword1}
Some text...
\printVariable % this should, in this case, print 'keyword1'
The rest of the text
\end{document}
```

If this is not what you're looking for, you should refine the question.