# Defining dynamic numeric variables and adding them

Tags: variable

I'm designing an academic exam template, and would like to assign specific point values to individual questions, and then sum the point values on a given page to display at the bottom of that page.  I THINK this requires the following: 1) creating numeric variables (in the preamble, I assume), 2) dynamically updating these in the body of the document (for each page, which will have different numbers of questions with different point values), and 3) summing these variables to print out a result. This post [Defining a dynamic variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186582/defining-a-dynamic-variable) has given me a good sense of where to start, but I wonder if anyone has more direct experience with doing this sort of thing?  [Using TexPad, w XeLaTeX by default, if this matters].

In the end the page would look like:
Question 1 [X points]....
Question 2 [Y points]....
Question 3 [Z points]....
Page total = W = X + Y + Z.

Where X, Y, Z, and W are numbers that change within the document itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is a bit too generic. Can you please give some more details?

Comment: The easy way is to create a counter before the beginning of the document (`\newcounter{mypagepoints}`). Then define the question to need as an argument the (integer) number of the points and i for example this argument is #1 to contain `\addtocounter{mypagepoints}{#1}`. The total will be printed in the end of the page by a command like `\newcommand\printpagerpoints{\thepagepoints\setcounter{totalpoints}{\value{mypagepoints}}\setcounter{mypagepoints}{0}}` (I added a counter for total points if needed too). This command resets the `pagepoints` and stores its old value to `tolalpoints` counter

Comment: Thanks much @koleygr.  It hadn't occurred to me to use a counter, when that was clearly the simplest way. I ended up with the following: `\newcounter{mypagepoints}
\newcounter{totalpoints}
\newcommand\printpagepoints{\themypagepoints\setcounter{totalpoints}{\value{mypagepoints}}\setcounter{mypagepoints}{0}}` in the preamble, and then `\addtocounter{mypagepoints}{#1}` and `\printpagepoints` on each page, where #1 was a numeric point value. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome but doesn't seem really automated to me... If you add a MWE we can find a better way... I don't know what a question is in your case and how is defined

Comment: Sure thing.  Here's a MWE.  `\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\newcounter{mypagepoints}
\newcounter{totalpoints}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\printpagepoints{
 \themypagepoints\addtocounter{totalpoints}{\value{mypagepoints}}\setcounter{mypagepoints}{0}
 }
Question 1 [10 points]
Text of question 1
\addtocounter{mypagepoints}{10} 
\hspace*{\fill} out of \printpagepoints
\newpage
Question 2 [10 points]
Text of question 2
\addtocounter{mypagepoints}{5} 
\hspace*{\fill} out of \printpagepoints
{\thetotalpoints} total points
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

I simplified it a little according to your example (you could just edit your post... A comment is not appropriate for MWE)

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\newcounter{cquestion}
\newcounter{mypagepoints}
\newcounter{totalpoints}
\newcommand\printpagepoints{%
  \themypagepoints\addtocounter{totalpoints}{\value{mypagepoints}}%
  \setcounter{mypagepoints}{0}%
}
\newcommand\question[2][10]{%
  \addtocounter{mypagepoints}{#1}
  \stepcounter{cquestion}%
  Question \thecquestion\ [#1 points] #2%may be a \par here
  \hfill out of \printpagepoints
}

\begin{document}
\question{Text of question 1}\newpage
\question[5]{Text of question 2}
\thetotalpoints total points
\end{document}
```

I would chose a different style and I didn't knew if every page has onlu one question... So this is what I can do so far for you

Some explanation:
\question command takes two arguments... First is optional and is the points. Default points (if no optional given) 10. The second argument is the text of the question. Then as you see in the main code almost everything you need is automated... But I don't really know the style of your questions... If more than one question can be in the same page... where you want to print totalpoints etc.